# checking next element in for loop

Tags: python

Let's say I have this array:

```
arr = ["foo","bar","hey"]
```

I can print the `"foo"` string with this code :

```
for word in arr:
    if word == "foo":
        print word
```

But I want also check the next `word` if it equals to `"bar"` then it should print `"foobar"`

How can I check the next element in a for loop?

Comment: Why not use `elif` or `else`?

Comment: You can get the answer you're looking for by reviewing [2395160](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395160/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-else-if)

Comment: @EliKorvigo: I think the OP simply wants to have access to the current and next element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] == "foo":
        if arr[i+1] == 'bar':
            print arr[i] + arr[i+1]
        else:
            print arr[i]
```

Comment: I believe the more pythonic way would be to use `enumerate()` rather than iterating based on the `len` of a list.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely better way to do that with `enumerate()`

Answer (score 6):

The items in a list can be referred to by their index. Using the `enumerate()` method to receive an iterator along with each list element (preferable to the C pattern of instantiating and incrementing your own), you can do so like this:

```
arr = ["foo","bar","hey"]

for i, word in enumerate(arr):
    if word == "foo" and arr[i+1] == 'bar':
        print word
```

However, when you get to the end of the list, you will encounter an `IndexError` that needs to be handled, or you can get the length (`len()`) of the list first and ensure `i < max`.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than check for the next value, track the *previous*:

```
last = None
for word in arr:
    if word == "foo":
        print word
    if last == 'foo' and word == 'bar':
        print 'foobar'
    last = word
```

Tracking what you already passed is easier than peeking ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with zip:

```
for cur, next in zip(arr, arr[1:]):
    if nxt=='bar':
        print cur+nxt
```

But keep in mind that the number of iterations will be only two since `len(ar[1:])` will be 2