# Get value from an "if " statement with multiple conditions

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement, multiple-conditions, getvalue

I have an Excel file and I want to extract some values from it whe it finds 7 or 14 or 13 in the following columns: remainingDaysE or remainingDaysG or remainingDaysI

I am having the following code in Python:

```
if remainingDaysE == 7 or  remainingDaysG == 7 or \
            remainingDaysE == 14 or remainingDaysG == 14 or \`enter code here`
            remainingDaysE == 30 or  remainingDaysG == 30:
            

            # create an email with values extracted
```

One of the values that I need would be the value that gets me in the "If statement"

My question is: Is there any to get the value that got me into this is "if" statement? E.G: Was it remainingDaysE == 7 or was it remainingDaysG ==30 etc.. How do I get that specific value or is there any other way to reformat the code? I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Handle each condition separately, [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395167/3386109).

Comment: Do you just need to know the value (7, 14, 30) or do you also need to know which column it came from?

Comment: Only the values 7, 14, 30

Comment: @LeonardBasag In that case my Answer should work for you

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with the code you provided in your post. I hade to make up some variables as we don't have all the code:

```
remainingDaysE = 14
remainingDaysG = 43

def createemail(remainingDays):
    print("pretending to create email with: "+remainingDays+"remaning Days")

def remainingdayfunction():
    if remainingDaysE == 7 or remainingDaysE == 14 or remainingDaysE == 30:
        return createemail(remainingDaysE)
    if remainingDaysG == 7 or remainingDaysG == 14 or remainingDaysG == 30:
        return createemail(remainingDaysG)
remainingdayfunction()
```

Comment: This sounds really good, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `and` keyword is a logical operator, `and` is used to combine conditional statements.

```
a = 200
b = 33
c = 500
if a > b and c > a:
  print("Both conditions are True")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know the number of remaining days then you could do this:

```
remainingDaysE = 7
remainingDaysG = 99
remainingDaysI = 44

def create_email(remainingDays):
    pass

for remainingDays in remainingDaysE, remainingDaysG, remainingDaysI:
    if remainingDays in {7, 14, 30}:
        create_email(remainingDays)
        break
```