# SyntaxError: expected ':'

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

what should I do?

I gave this error:

```py
mylist=input('please inter your condition :')
If mylist == '10' or '9' or '8':
   print('well')
   print('well done')
else if mylist == '7' or'6' or '5' or '4' or '3':
   print('mid') 
   print('moderate') 
else if mylist == '2'   or '1':
   print('weak')
else print('0')  

 File "<ipython-input-42-fc470037cf12>", line 5
    else if mylist == '7' or'6' or '5' or '4' or '3':
         ^
SyntaxError: expected ':'
```

I change space between : and  '
but ....
what should Ido?

Comment: You must be on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking questions.

Comment: You need to do `elif:` not `else if:`. That's just the way python works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct syntax for 'else if'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395160/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-else-if)

Comment: There are many more things wrong with this code besides what is complained about.

Answer (score -1):

In Python, there are three forms of the if...else statement :

if statement

if...else statement

if...elif...else statement