# 'ELSE' Running even if 'If' is true

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I was Trying to Make a Simple Maths Calculator.

```
pi = math.pi
e = math.e
φ = 1.618033988749895

while True:
    sh= input("MATHS CALCULATOR: ")

    if sh== "Values":
        va=input("NAME OF VALUE: ")
        if va=="pi":
            print("PI value is", pi)

        elif va=="PI":
            print("PI value is", pi)

        elif va=="e":
            print("Euler's Number(e) value is", e)

        elif va=="g":
            print("Golden Ratio(φ) value is", φ)

        else:
            print("Try Another")

    if sh== "Simple":
        sim=input("ENTER AN OPERATOR: ")
        a=int(input("ENTER FIRST NUMBER: "))
        b=int(input("ENTER SECOND NUMBER: "))
        if sim=="+":
            c=a+b
            print(a,"PLUS",b,"EQUALS",c)
        elif sim=="*":
            c=a*b
            print(a,"TIMES",b,"EQUALS",c)
        elif sim=="x":
            c=a*b
            print(a,"TIMES",b,"EQUALS",c)
        elif sim=="/":
            c=a/b
            print(a,"BY",b,"EQUALS",c)
        elif sim=="-":
            c=a-b
            print(a,"MINUS",b,"EQUALS",c)
        else:
            print("Try Another")

    if sh=="Stop":
        print("Thanks For Using!")
        quit()

    else:
        print("Check Again the Spelling!")
```

I tried Everything from changing The entire Program.
I also Tried to Remove the loop,
Nothing Worked.
All lead to this.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUVXP.png)
I expect the code to only Show the 'ELSE' message when Nothing Matches.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct syntax for 'else if'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395160/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-else-if)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the main `if`s are uncorrelated in that way, meaning that every one is checked separately from the others. The last else is only combined with the last `if`. To solve your problem, you should do something like this:

```py
pi = math.pi
e = math.e
φ = 1.618033988749895

while True:
    sh= input("MATHS CALCULATOR: ")

    if sh== "Values":
        va=input("NAME OF VALUE: ")
        if va=="pi":
            print("PI value is", pi)

        elif va=="PI":
            print("PI value is", pi)

        elif va=="e":
            print("Euler's Number(e) value is", e)

        elif va=="g":
            print("Golden Ratio(φ) value is", φ)

        else:
            print("Try Another")

    elif sh== "Simple":
        sim=input("ENTER AN OPERATOR: ")
        a=int(input("ENTER FIRST NUMBER: "))
        b=int(input("ENTER SECOND NUMBER: "))
        if sim=="+":
            c=a+b
            print(a,"PLUS",b,"EQUALS",c)
        elif sim=="*":
            c=a*b
            print(a,"TIMES",b,"EQUALS",c)
        elif sim=="x":
            c=a*b
            print(a,"TIMES",b,"EQUALS",c)
        elif sim=="/":
            c=a/b
            print(a,"BY",b,"EQUALS",c)
        elif sim=="-":
            c=a-b
            print(a,"MINUS",b,"EQUALS",c)
        else:
            print("Try Another")

    elif sh=="Stop":
        print("Thanks For Using!")
        quit()

    else:
        print("Check Again the Spelling!")
```

In this way, only one of the `sh ==`/`else` condition is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `elif` instead of `if`.

```
sh = input(...)
if sh == "Values":
   ...
elif sh == "Simple":
   ...
elif sh == "Stop":
   ...
else:
    print("Check spelling")
```

Comment: Thanks, I left out Such a simple thing.